# PostgreSQL query for determining cohorts of data by timestamp and name

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have data that has a timestamp and a name like:

| ts | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | Place A (123) |
| 2021-10-01 00:01:00 | Place A (123) |
| 2021-10-01 00:06:00 | Place A (123) |
| 2021-10-01 00:10:00 | Place B (234) |
| 2021-10-01 00:13:00 | Place B (234) |
| 2021-10-01 00:15:00 | Place C (345) |
| 2021-10-01 00:18:00 | Place C (345) |
| 2021-10-01 00:23:00 | Place C (345) |
| 2021-10-01 00:27:00 | Place C (345) |
| 2021-10-01 00:28:00 | Place C (345) |
| 2021-10-01 00:29:00 | Place C (345) |
| 2021-10-01 00:30:00 | Place A (123) |
| 2021-10-01 00:33:00 | Place A (123) |

I am wanting to build a query that will allow for finding "cohorts" of process cycle sessions where:

- someone is going through steps of a cycle and will repeat the same
  process or start a new process
- data_timestamp is ordered ASC
- name is the step they are currently in
- different cycles will have the same name, which can repeat multiple times over time, but may not be in the same order
- returns the following columns:

  - MIN(data_timestamp) for a name before a different name
  - MAX(data_timestamp) for a name before a different name
  - name

The end result should be something like:

| min_data_timestamp | max_data_timestamp | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 2021-10-01 00:06:00 | Place A (123) |
| 2021-10-01 00:10:00 | 2021-10-01 00:13:00 | Place B (123) |
| 2021-10-01 00:15:00 | 2021-10-01 00:29:00 | Place C (123) |
| 2021-10-01 00:30:00 | 2021-10-01 00:33:00 | Place A (123) |

I am assuming some type of windowing query/CTE to do this. I have seen other examples that find start/end time overall for a name or something similar, but not where the name is repeated throughout.

*EDIT* had a few typos

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` with `group by`:

```
with pr as (
   select row_number() over (order by id) r, id, name from processes
),
pr1 as (
   select p.*, (select sum(case when p1.r < p.r and p1.name != p.name then 1 end) from pr p1) gid from pr p
)
select min(p.id), max(p.id), max(p.name)
from pr1 p group by p.gid order by case when p.gid is null then 1 else p.gid end;
```

Output:

| min_data_timestamp | max_data_timestamp | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 2021-10-01 00:06:00 | Place A (123) |
| 2021-10-01 00:10:00 | 2021-10-01 00:13:00 | Place B (234) |
| 2021-10-01 00:15:00 | 2021-10-01 00:29:00 | Place C (345) |
| 2021-10-01 00:30:00 | 2021-10-01 00:33:00 | Place A (123) |